# Saving data for 3 days using NSUserDefaults?

Tags: objective-c, nsuserdefaults

Is it possible to save the NSUserDefaults data for 3 days and than go back to it was again using the below code? Don't have a clue where to put the time trigger :(

```
#define k_Save @"MAKENEW"

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    NSUserDefaults *saveapp = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
    bool saved = [saveapp boolForKey:k_Save];
    if (!saved) {

        _level2Button.hidden = YES;

        _purchaseController = [[PurchaseViewController alloc]init];

        [[SKPaymentQueue defaultQueue]
         addTransactionObserver:_purchaseController];

    } else {

        _level2Button.enabled = YES;
        _level2Button.hidden = NO;
    };
}

-(void)enableLevel2
{
    _level2Button.enabled = YES;
    _level2Button.hidden = NO;
    NSUserDefaults *saveapp = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
    [saveapp setBool:TRUE forKey:k_Save];
    [saveapp synchronize];
}
```

Thank you for your answer.

Answer (score 0):

You need to code it, there is no automatic option like that.

If each time you call `setBool:...forKey:...` you also call `setObject:[NSDate date] forKey:...` then you can later check what the stored date is and use `removeObjectForKey:` to clear the saved `BOOL` (and date).

Answer (score 0):

You have to manage it manually like this.

You can store date in NSUserDefaults and then compare it when application enter in foreground.  If it is greater than 3 day then remove your object object.

Answer (score 0):

Add another flag, when the key was stored and check that aswell.

```
-(void)enableLevel2
{
    _level2Button.enabled = YES;
    _level2Button.hidden = NO;
    NSUserDefaults *saveapp = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
    [saveapp setBool:TRUE forKey:k_Save];
    [saveapp setObject:[NSDate date] forKey:k_EnabledLebel2Date];
    [saveapp synchronize];
}
```

And perform the check as followed:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    NSUserDefaults *saveapp = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
    bool saved = [saveapp boolForKey:k_Save];
    NSDate *saveDate = [saveapp objectForKey:k_EnabledLebel2Date];
    if (saveDate && [[NSDate date] timeIntervalSinceDate:saveDate] > 3 * 24 * 60 *60)
    {
         [saveapp setBool:NO forKey:k_Save];
         [saveapp setObject:nil forKey:k_EnabledLebel2Date];
         saved = NO;
    }
    if (!saved) {

        _level2Button.hidden = YES;

        _purchaseController = [[PurchaseViewController alloc]init];

        [[SKPaymentQueue defaultQueue]
         addTransactionObserver:_purchaseController];

    } else {

        _level2Button.enabled = YES;
        _level2Button.hidden = NO;
    };
}
```

Comment: Is it count as days, hours, minutes seconds? Thnx. Can you please explain what you mean by "Add another flag, when the key was stored and check that aswell."

Comment: I introduced another flag: k_EnabledLebel2Date, which is used to identify the date, when the user was granted the access to level 2. This is stored as [NSDate date] (which access the current date) - lateron we will check, whether the 3 days have passed: 3 days * 24 hours * 60 minutes * 60 seconds:     if ([[NSDate date] timeIntervalSinceDate:saveDate] > 3 * 24 * 60 *60)

Comment: Unfortunally it doesn't work, I added the new flag "#define k_EnabledLebel2Date @"DAYS" now the level2button is already enabled and got a warning "unused variable saved" on bool saved = [saveapp boolForKey:k_Save];